# How to Trigger Code with ComboBox Change Event

Tags: vb.net, oledb, textchanged, lost-focus

I have a created a database containing historical stock prices.  On my form I have two comboboxes, `ComboBox_Ticker` and `ComboBox_Date`.  When these comboboxes are filled I want to check the database and see if the respective data exists in the database.  If it does I want to change the text of a label called `Label_If_Present` to "In Database".

My problem occurs with the change event.  I want all of this to happen once I change the data in the textboxes.  I have tried both the `.TextChanged` and `.LostFocus` events.  The '.TextChanged' triggers the code to early and throws and error in my SQL command statement.  The `.LostFocus' event doesn't do trigger my code at all.

Here is my current code:

```
Public databaseName As String = "G:\Programming\Nordeen Investing 3\NI3 Database.mdb"
Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" & databaseName)
Public tblName As String = "Historical_Stock_Prices"

Private Sub Change_Labels(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_Ticker.TextChanged, ComboBox_Date.TextChanged
    con.Close()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    con.Open()
    If (File.Exists(databaseName)) Then
        Dim restrictions(3) As String
        restrictions(2) = tblName
        Dim dbTbl As DataTable = con.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
        If dbTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Else
            Dim cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & tblName & " WHERE  Ticker = '" & ComboBox_Ticker.Text & "' " & "  AND  Date1 = '" & ComboBox_Date.Text & "'", con)
            dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
            If dr.Read() = 0 Then
                'If record does not exist
                Label_If_Present.Text = ""
            Else
                Label_If_Present.Text = "In Database"
            End If
            con.Close()
        End If
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

I have successfully implemented this concept on other forms within my project.  This one is slightly different and I can't figure out why I can't get this one to work.

Comment: SelectedItemChanged or SelectedIndexChanged (or something like that) would be my usual choice for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

Handling the `TextChanged` event should work, however you need to set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` so that the Text property can only be a given value.
Then check to see that both comboboxes have values selected.  Something like this should work:

```
  If ComboBox_Ticker.Text <> "" AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(ComboBox_Date.Text, Nothing) Then
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to check the date ticker for an actual date with `DateTime.TryParse(ComboBox_Date.Text, Nothing)` rather than just any text. Also ought to look into [command parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) to help avoid injection attacks.

Comment: This partially worked.  Originally I couldn't complete even one combobox.  Now I can fill in one comobobox but as soon as I type one thing into the other the error comes up again.  It won't wait until I've finished typing in both comboboxes.

Comment: @kwwallpe This is the error that I receive `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: I didn't realize you were letting the user type info in without validating it, instead of only allowing a selection from the dropdownlist.  I modified my answer.  I assumed the Combobox_Ticker contains only text, if it is supposed to be formatted as well, you'll have to add code to validate it too, before you query the database.

Comment: The data type mismatch is because you're surrounding a date data type with single quotes instead of pound signs in your query. Access needs dates to be enclosed in pound signs like `#1/1/2013#`. Yet another reason to use parameters instead: `Dim cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & tblName & " WHERE Ticker = ? AND Date1 = ?", con)` Followed by `cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox_Ticker.Text)` and `cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox_Date.Text)`